# Make CSS animations fluid while JavaScript runs?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on an Ember app and it shows a lot of real time data, it makes the JS thread really busy.

I'd like to add some nice fluid animation with CSS3 but having JS which works under the hood makes the entire app laggy.

Is there a way to give priority to the CSS animations to make them fluid?
After all I don't care if for half second my data is not updated.

I mostly target Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look into webworkers.

If you let all your ajax and dataprocessing be done by the webworker thread, and the displaying only by the DOM thread you can save a lot of overhead/delays caused by computations.

One word of advice. Don't do worker.postMessage(arg,arg) but do worker.postMessage(arg) with a single argument.

The object itself will be posted then instead of it being converted to json and converted back in the other thread. Saves a lot of cpu time.
Keep in mind that the thread that posted the object will have "lost" the object(to prevent concurrency problems)

Also DOM elements cannot be posted to a webworker, so make sure your data is "clean" if you post to the worker.

Comment: I don't think it would be easy, Ember works in a different manner and implementing web workers could be really hard..

Comment: Javascript is javascript. All you have to do is make a javascript object `var x={};x.calculate = somearray;x.points = somearraywithobjects;worker.postMessage(x);` Remember, ember uses javascript, does not override it. Would be easier if you have some sample code what gets calculated/processed, but in essence you clean up the data, post it to worker, get it back, and render everything you need.

Comment: I have found a plugin for Ember to implement web workers, I'll try to propose it to my team. Thanks!  https://github.com/bengillies/ember-parallel

Answer (score 1):

Maybe trying to get the CSS animations to be [rendered by the GPU](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css) would be an possibility.

CPU and GPU would run seperate, You should give it a try and see if it gives you an improvement!

Comment: Even with the GPU animations are a bit laggy, and it's not really easy make every element which needs a transition use GPU. By the way I'll try to implement it wherever possible. Thanks!